# 2012 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2012 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: Do current moderators need to be re-elected?  Or are we electing *additional* members of the team? This wasn't made clear by the announcement post on the main site.

Comment: Current moderators stay elected, the election is for 3 new moderators.

Comment: Can we only nominate *ourselves*, or can we nominate others?

Comment: Only self nomination, there's some background [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1303/what-is-the-reason-for-insisting-on-self-nomination)

Comment: @ChipBennett You should nominate yourself. You've my vote :)

Comment: IMHO: Moderators should be forced to use a real photo as their profile picture. Just to give WPSE more of a face.

Comment: @kaiser LOL... you hadn't seen avatar wall in mod chatroom... Not really in the culture :)

Comment: @kaiser I've been asked, and I'm considering it; but for a few reasons, I'm leaning toward declining. I'll post an answer below, for discussion.

Comment: @kaiser With the exception of Rarst (just because I'm so used to it now) I completely agree. Using a real photo adds something to the reputation.

Comment: its that exciting time of the year again :)

Comment: Can nominees vote in the election?

Comment: @Jared yes (if I remember right - I don't remember not being able to last time)

Answer (score 3):

(If this isn't the appropriate place for such discussion, feel free to delete this answer.)

I've been asked by a couple people to nominate myself, and am considering it; but I have reservations:

1. I don't think I have the time to commit to the *responsibility* of being a moderator.
2. As is evidenced by many of my questions here on Meta, I'm not confident in my own understanding of certain things (namely, scope; but also, the nuances of some of the site mechanics) to be able to become a *decision-maker* regarding those things.
3. I'm one of 6 total people (and one of only 4 non-moderators) with access to Moderator Tools. If I were elected moderator, I would gain a few more privileges, but those additional privileges wouldn't represent a huge improvement in the overall ability of the community to self-moderate. I would rather see someone else equally qualified, but with lower rep, be elected and gain full moderator privileges. That way, the "pool" of moderation resources increases more.

Perhaps this is all an exercise in navel-gazing. I'll do whatever the WPSE community wants, and am willing to help to the extent I am able to commit. I just wanted to throw these things out for discussion.

Comment: There are some users like toscho and me who aren't that far away from those tools, so I wouldn't give too much about the number of people who have access to those. +/-1 doesn't matter. So go and nominate yourself :)

Comment: I look at the current slate of 5 self-nominees, and realize that I would vote for *every one of them* before I would vote for myself. I think we already have the slate of best candidates.

Comment: Same goes for me. You should nominate yourself anyway :)